# How to code a jButton to turn the laptop or device to battery saver mode

Tags: java, windows, swing, jbutton, jcheckbox

I haven't tried any coding, because I'm inexperienced.

But for an application I'm currently making (for an assignment) I want to enable the user to turn the battery saver mode when the count down ended, (if the user previously selected the 'turn battery saver when resting' checkbox) the power-saver mode will be automatically enabled by the software. (OS - Windows 10).

Comment: Doing that would require the programming language to get deep into the guts of the OS. Java is **not** that language, as it takes a 'higher level' approach which tries to work across all machines. BTW *"I'm inexperienced. .. (for an assignment)"* A **good** instructor / teacher would realize this was not a job for Java, so I'm guessing you're trying to do this above and beyond the task assigned. Just .. **don't**. Your time would be better spent (and the teacher more impressed) if the code for the assigned task was well written and well documented. Save these extras for your own apps.

Comment: The command line would be something like `powercfg.exe /setactive ...`. With ProcessBuilder you could execute such a command line. (1) Find exact command line working. (2) Execute such a command in Java with ProcessBuilder. Or you could separate things by trying first to start Notepad.exe with ProcessBuilder.

Comment: What is your os? If it's android, please use the tag.

Comment: @NomadMaker please read the post :) OP did tell what the OS is ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement such an action by executing a cmd command via the [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).
I have put together a program that works for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  frame.setSize(200, 200);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.add(panel);

  JButton button = new JButton("Standby");
  panel.add(button);
  frame.setVisible(true);

  button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState");
      builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
      try {
        builder.start();
      } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Maybe you need to change the command "rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState" to something else.